# JS element toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

(`getProperty` is the `deepCss` function from [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?166053-Check-if-element-is-visible-when-style-not-set-in-the-tag&p=825130#post825130) and retrieves the current (computed) style of an element).

```
function toggleElements()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        $(arguments[i])[0].style.display = (
            getProperty($(arguments[i])[0], "display") !== "none"
                ? "none"
                : "inline-block");
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
<div id="searchdiv" onclick="toggleElements('#searchoplus', 
                                            '#searchominus', 
                                            '#search_simple', 
                                            '#search_extended');">
```

which will switch on those elements in the list that weren't visible, and switch off those that were.

I guess I can get rid of the for loop and use jQuery's idiomatic chained-expression syntax, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My jQuery's a bit rusty but if `#searchoplus`, `#searchominus`, etc. initially have a display value of `inline-block` you should be able to get your code down to:

```
function toggleElements() {
  $.each(arguments, function(index, id) {
    $(id).toggle();
  });
}
```

[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) saves the initial value of the display and puts it back in place when it's re-toggled.

Comment: `searchoplus` and `search_simple` have `display: inline-block` while `searchominus` and `search_extended` initially have `display: none`. See my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain I understood what you want, but this should at least be a starting point.

I have assumed that "idiomatic chained-expression syntax" is referring to chainable methods. In other words you could write this:

```
setElements('#searchoplus', 
            '#searchominus', 
            '#search_simple', 
            '#search_extended').toggle().doSomethingElse();
```

To accomplish this, you need to create a **function** that **returns an object** that has a **method that also returns the object**.

```
function setElements(){

    //This is the class for creating the object
    function elObj(argumentz){

        //This method toggles and then returns the 'elObj' object
        this.toggle=function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < argumentz.length; i++) {
                $(argumentz[i])[0].style.display = (
                    document.getProperty($(argumentz[i])[0], "display") !== "none"
                        ? "none"
                        : "inline-block");
            }
            return this;
        }

        //This is another method that also returns the object
        this.doSomethingElse=function(){
            console.log("Something else");
            return this;                    
        }
    }


    //Create the new object and return it
    return new elObj(arguments);

}
```

Here is the full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Mpcs/7/

Comment: I definitely misunderstood. I was thinking you wanted a non-jQuery solution...

Comment: Just making sure, you don't want to just use `$('#searchoplus,#searchominus,#search_simple,#search_extended')`, right?

Comment: +1 Well, this is still a valuable answer, even though I was looking for a way to utilize the *existing* power of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that there are two possibilities.

#### 1. The literal translation:

```
function toggleElements()
{
    $(arguments).each(function (index, element) {
        $(element)[0].style.display = (
            getProperty($(element)[0], "display") !== "none"
                ? "none"
                : "inline-block");
    });
}
```

#### 2. Using `toggle()`:

```
function toggleElements()
{
    $(arguments).each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).toggle();
    });
}
```

This second version needs a workaround to use the `display: inline-block` attribute correctly. You need to specify this attribute in your CSS file even for elements which are hidden when the page is loaded, and hide them by setting `display: none` in the `style` attribute of the element itself to get the correct behaviour with the jQuery `toggle` function.

Comment: Be careful using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), it's only meant for iterating over jQuery objects and can cause problems when used on anything else. [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is the safe alternative :)